# uploading multiple images to db with 2 text fields

Tags: php, mysql, html, image, file-upload

okay I have a dilemma. I am want to be able to upload a maximum of six images and 2 text field (title and desc) into the db... actually let me correct myself, I want to store the name of the images in the db so I can get the pics later. I know how to upload multiple pics to a folder, and I know how to insert rows into the db, but I cant figure out how to combine the two. how would I combine this with images work, cancelling the whole process if one of the files has an issue?

my db setup is simply id | title | desc | img1 | img2 | img3 | img4 | img5 | img6

the code i wrote so far is:

```
if (isset($_POST['formsubmitted'])) { //if form was submitted
$error = array();//Declare An Array to store any error message  

if (empty($_POST['title'])) {//if no name has been supplied 
    $error[] = 'Please enter a title for your post.';//add to array "error"
    $show_errors = 'show';
} else {
    $title = $_POST['title'];//else assign it a variable
}



if (empty($_POST['desc'])) {
    $error[] = 'Please enter a short desc of your post.';//add to array "error"
    $show_errors = 'show';
} else {
    $desc = $_POST['desc'];//else assign it a variable
}



    if (empty($error)){ //if no error, insert into db

$new_post = "INSERT INTO `posts` ( `title`, `desc`) VALUES ( '$title', '$desc')";
    $result = mysql_query($new_post ) or die(mysql_error('error inserting post'));

}


}
```

then the html is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<?php if (isset($show_errors)) { 
    //show user the errors if form cant be submitted
    echo '<div> <ol>';
        foreach ($error as $key => $values) { echo '    <li>'.$values.'</li>'; }
        echo '</ol></div><br />'; }?>

<br />
<form method="post" id="newpost" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<div><input name="title" type="text" value="" class="title_input"></div>
<div><textarea id="area4" cols="40" rows="5" name="desc" class="desc_texbox"></textarea></div>
<div><input type="file" name="images1"></div>
<div><input type="file" name="images2"></div>
<div><input type="file" name="images3"></div>
<div><input type="file" name="images4"></div>
<div><input type="file" name="images5"></div>
<div><input type="file" name="images6"></div>
<input type="hidden" name="formsubmitted" value="TRUE" />
<input type="submit" id="upload" value="Upload">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I would suggest starting by normalising your data structure by moving the images into an images table instead of having the repeated field set in the posts table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is by no means finished but it should get you heading in the right direction. Note that I have done this based on changing the file fields be renamed like `<input type="file" name="images[1]" />` so that they get processed as an array.

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', true);

$db = new PDO('mysql:dbname=test;host=127.0.0.1', 'user', 'pass');


if (isset($_POST['formsubmitted'])) { //if form was submitted

    $error_array = array();//Declare An Array to store any error message

    // check all images for upload errors
    // you should probably add extra file validation here - check image type etc
    $upload_error = false;
    foreach($_FILES['images']['error'] as $error) {
        if ($error != 0 && $error != 4) {
            $upload_error = true;
        }
    }

    if ($upload_error) {
        $error_array[] = 'One of the image uploads failed!';
    }


    if (empty($_POST['title'])) {//if no name has been supplied
        $error_array[] = 'Please enter a title for your post.';//add to array "error"
    } else {
        $title = $_POST['title'];//else assign it a variable
    }

    if (empty($_POST['desc'])) {
        $error_array[] = 'Please enter a short desc of your post.';//add to array "error"
    } else {
        $desc = $_POST['desc'];//else assign it a variable
    }

    if (empty($error_array)){ //if no error, insert into db

        $new_post = "INSERT INTO `posts` ( `title`, `desc`) VALUES (?, ?)";
        $stmt = $db->prepare($new_post);
        $stmt->execute(array($title, $desc));

        $new_post_id = $db->lastInsertId();

        // now start processing the images
        $image_sql = "INSERT INTO `post_images` (`post_id`, `img_name`) VALUES (?, ?)";
        $stmt = $db->prepare($image_sql);

        for ($i = 1; $i <= 6; $i++) {

            // you need to add some code to vlaidate, move and rename the files

            // add the files to the db
            $file_name = $_FILES['images']['name'][$i];
            $stmt->execute(array($new_post_id, $file_name));

        }

    } else {
        print_r($error_array);
    }

}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think is better, first to upload the images on the server, if the move_uploaded_file() function returns error, add a value in $error array.
 In this way, the data will be inserted in database only if the upload was succesfully completed.